# Build image on Openshift via internal jenkins

Tags: jenkins, openshift

Currently I'm trying to convert my regular jenkinsjob to work with jenkins in openshift. Currently, I'm checking out on git, build a war file, copy the war file to another directory with only a dockerfile(same workspace ofcourse). Do dockerbuild and push to a registry.

Now, I've managed to follow the Openshift's jenkins example a bit, I've managed to use the jenkins-slave-maven pod and build my package(WAR) with that. But ofcourse I can't build the docker image and push it to the internal Openshift registry(Because docker is not installed on the slave-maven image??).

What is the correct way to do this, without exposing docker.sock?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We use [docker swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) with the [jenkins swarm plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Swarm+Plugin)

You just need a docker container which you then open up to Jenkins via the plugin.

Good [video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xqxoR7UzF4A)